# Down-voting Stolen Answers etiquette

Tags: discussion, down-votes, etiquette

There have been a few times where I have come across a question with a wrong or incomplete answer, provided a correct answer and then had the original answerer edit/correct/expand their answer to match mine.

If this is done quickly enough the stolen answer often gets the up-votes (it was answered earlier) and sometimes is marked as the correct answer (which at that point, it is).

I am not against people correcting wrong answers (especially little mistakes) or making some revisions. Nor am I against the idea of up-voting multiple correct answers - although I rarely do it when there are duplicate answers, I just up-vote the one that got there first.

All that to say, **what is the general etiquette when you have had your answer stolen?** I could leave a comment but that would tend to make me look like a petty jerk. I could down-vote the answer, but the answer is now correct so I'm really down-voting the user which may feel good to me, but be misleading to other users. Or I could just suck it up, be irritated, delete my "duplicate" answer and move on - this seems like the most mature, if least satisfying, response.

Perhaps there is a middle ground or precedent that I am unaware of for these types of situations?

Comment: Hehe, I once had a question *asker* take my answer, edit it into another person's *wrong* answer, and then grant a bounty to *that*. Guess you'll just have to live with it...

Comment: @Arjan: +1 for "live with it".

Comment: Well, @Shog9, to be honest I first tried to get a reason from the question asker, but failing a response, I indeed learned to live with it... :-)

Comment: I am *so* tempted to copy & paste one of the answers below as my own

Comment: @Pekka Dare you to. Go on, it'll be great, etc. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh it depends on where you live (tag) in SE.  In some lower population tags, the competition can be rather intensive. However, the only professional approach would be to move `on`.  Due to the grace period, it is a lost cause for you to pursue any action. *(Even after deleting your competing answer, any 10k user can see it).*

I reckon if you are concerned more about rep than correct answers, it is time to move `out` of the site for a while and breathe some fresh air.

Your answer has been borg-ed and it is now part of the SE collective, even if you are not attached to it.

Comment: It's only temporarily if you're trying to say that they won't see it when they drop below 10k. Standard question deletion leaves a post that can be seen by 10k users and moderators at all times.

Comment: @Grace. Great to know that. I thought I read that deleted answers with no activity is culled.

Answer (score 6):

I find this happens rarely, rarely enough for me to grit my teeth and move on.

Comment: but boy do I grit my teeth